# Merging contiguous polygons and polygons that are within 50m of one another

Tags: python, numpy, geospatial, geopandas, arcpy

Can someone please help me with solving this question in python, arcpy, or arcgis pro. I have a feature class (a polygon shapefile), please see the image. I want to, where Current_RE is NOT “Water”, merge contiguous polygons and polygons that are within 50m of one another (make patches of polygons), UNLESS they are separated by a polygon where Current_RE = “Water”. I mean, regardless the 50 meter distances, the patches on opposite sides of a major watercourse to be considered separate. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the ArcGIS [aggregate polygons](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/cartography/aggregate-polygons.htm) tool. It should be able to do what you are looking for.